# How to check if WebBrowser is ready

Tags: c#

i'm doing a simple program that must open a page and fill some 
fields with number(in the page), but before editing the html of the page, I must 
be sure that the page is loaded 100%, how could I check it constantly? Tried some stuff but didn't worked...

Comment: 1. Please add another tag to your post to clarify the context.  That tag should probably be either WinForms, WPF, or ASP.Net.  2. Please post the code that you tried, but didn't work.

Comment: I am sure you are looking for `WebBrowser`'s `Navigated` event, to handle it. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an event handler for the Webbrowser document completed event. See the link from msdn for further details and an example of implementation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2